# how to get currently logged in user role in grails/spock unit test

Tags: grails, spring-security, spock

```
 void "test saveSupervisor action"() {
    setup:
    def testUser = new User()
    controller.userAuthService = [currentUser: testUser]


    expect:
    //User supervisor= new User()
    User supervisor= new User(username: "sp123456",password: "pwd")
    supervisor.save()
    println "spv************ : "+ supervisor

    when:"When User NAME Given"
    controller.params.username = "sp123456"
    controller.saveSupervisor()

    then:
    response.redirectUrl.endsWith '/showsupervisor/id'
}`---controller code----`
   @Secured("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and (hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR') )")
@Transactional
def saveSupervisor(User userInstance) {


    if (userInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (userInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond userInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }


    userInstance.save flush:true

    def spvRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')



    UserRole.create userInstance, spvRole , true



}
```

But I think I am doingf some thing wrong
I have these user roles, ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_ADMIN
when a user with having both role_supervisor and role_admin  logged in to application then only he is given access to action savSupervisor(). How can I capture the logged in user's roles in the spock test??  I want to test if a user logged in with the roles ROLE_SUPERVISOR "and" ROLE_ADMIN then ONLY he is given access to saveSupervisor() method. I am using spring security, Please help me.

Comment: Not sure you can test this in a unit test

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773734/grails-2-4-4-testing-for-permission-where-spring-security-code-is-being-used

Comment: Hi Burt can you please let me know how to solve the problem? can i go for integration testing? Can you please give me a right direction for this scenario?